# Proving that a set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

### The question

Given a matrix $A_{ m \times n}$ and a compact set $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. the set $B$ defined below is compact?

$$B= \{Ax | x \in C\}$$

### What ive tried

I believe that $B$, becaue I could not think about any counterexample,  is compact so I need to prove that he is closed and limited. I think i could use that $||Ax|| \leq |A||x|$ to prove that it is a limited set, but, I don't know how to prove that he is closed, can someone please give me any ideas or advices on how to prove that? Any hints or dvices are more than welcome.

Comment: Take $C=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=I$?

Comment: Assume $m=n$ and $A=1_n$ (identity matrix). Then $B=C$. Is a closed set necessarily compact?

Comment: I forgot to edit the question. $C$ is also a compact set, my bad guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ defined by
$$x\mapsto Ax, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n,$$
is clearly continuous. Therefore $B$ is the continuous image of a compact subset $C$ and hence compact.

Comment: what a coincidence! ha ha ha..

Comment: Same time!! same answer..!! Ha ha ha

Answer (score 1):

We know that every matrix represents a linear transformation from some vector space to another. Here $A_{m\times n}$ represents a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$.

We know that Compactness is preserved under continuity (Continuous image of a compact set is compact).

We also know that every linear transformation is certainly **continuous** so $A$ is continuous and $B=\{Ax:x\in C\}$ is precisely the image of $C$ under $A$ hence $B$ is compact.